# Proxychains not working behind proxy

Tags: kali-linux, proxy, proxychains

I am able to access internet only behind a proxy `172.16.24.4:3128`. When I run proxychains with proxy given by Tor, then my proxychains works fine, but when I run proxychains with the proxy through which I access the Internet (i.e. `172.16.24.4:3128`), the proxychains don't work.

Here's the sorts of errors I get:

```
proxychains apt-get update
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease

Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                  
  Could not resolve 'dl.google.com'
Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates InRelease                          

Err http://dl.bintray.com jessie InRelease    

Err http://security.kali.org sana/updates Release.gpg                        
  Could not resolve 'security.kali.org'
Err http://dl.bintray.com jessie Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'dl.bintray.com'
```

Please help. I am having this issue for a year and I couldn't find a solution. I think the problem is with DNS lookup behind a proxy. I don't know I have tried everything. Nothing works.

One more thing. If I set `http_proxy` variable to `172.16.24.4:3128`, then also some of my applications work, so there's nothing work with the proxy.

Comment: Someone please answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not proxychain but DNS requests !

try to enable

```
proxy_dns
```

in your **/etc/proxychains.conf**

or fix your resolv.conf file to reach a DNS server inside your environment.

Comment: Its already enabled.

Comment: And I have 8.8.8.8 in my resolv.conf. Should it be something else, if yes then how should I determine what it should be?

Comment: @Lokesh ok, can you disable it (proxy_dns) and try without it

Comment: I tried that too.  It didn't work out.